# how does zeromq determine order of load balancing?

Tags: load-balancing, zeromq

The documentation explains which socket types use load balancing between connected peers, but it doesn't say how it does the load balancing. I'm curious if it's deterministic and if so, what it's based on (order connected, based on address, some internal hash, etc).

Comment: You can have more advanced load balancing by adding more messaging patterns: http://zguide.zeromq.org/py%3aall#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple list, with round-robin load balancing.

Comment: I understand. But what order is that list?